# How to create a nested list of parent/child objects using a function?

Tags: python, django, algorithm, function, data-structures

I'm new to Python and Django and I've encountered a problem I can't solve on my own for quite a long time.

I have a database that consists of a number objects and each object has one parent (except the first, the 'root' object) and no / one / several children. I need to create a function that takes some object (e.g. *States* in the provided case) and returns this object and recursively its descendants like this:

```
arr = ['States',
       ['Kansas', ['Lawrence', 'Topeka', ['Some Topeka Street', ['Some House on Some Topeka Street']]],
        'Illinois', ['Chicago', 'Springfield']]]
```

I want to get this kind of data structure and use it on Django's [unordered list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#unordered-list) filter.

As far as I know about algorithms I should make up a function that somehow should work like this:

```
def make_nested_list(item):
    if not item.children: # basic case
        # do something
    else:
        for child in item.children: # recursive case
            # do something
            make_nested_list(child) # function calls itself
    # maybe do something here
    # and finally return self-nested list
    return result
```

Everything I try turns out to be a mess. How can I do that?

**UPD:** Here is the model I work with:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,
                               null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @property
    def children(self):
        return self.thing_set.all()

    @property
    def siblings(self):
        return Thing.objects.filter(parent=self.parent)
```

Comment: Please provide the structure of `item`. You have only given code that makes access to a `children` property, but where is the string coming from that should be output in the list structure?

Comment: Thank you for your response! I've updated my question and added the structure of item.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `item` objects have `title` attributes, here is what you could do:

```
def list_nodes(siblings):
    for node in siblings:
        yield node.title
        if node.children:
            yield list(list_nodes(node.children))
```

So the argument to this function is a **list** of nodes. If you just have one root object, then first put it in a list, and pass that as argument:

```
result = list(list_nodes([root]))
```

Here is the test I performed, which includes the creation of mock data:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Node = namedtuple("Node", "title, children")

root = Node("States", [
    Node("Kansas", [
        Node("Lawrence", []), 
        Node("Topeka", [])
    ]), 
    Node("Illinois", [])
])

print(root)

def list_nodes(siblings):
    for node in siblings:
        yield node.title
        if node.children:
            yield list(list_nodes(node.children))

result = list(list_nodes([root]))

print(result)
```

This outputs (with some formatting applied):

```
Node(title='States', children=[
    Node(title='Kansas', children=[
        Node(title='Lawrence', children=[]), 
        Node(title='Topeka', children=[])
    ]),
    Node(title='Illinois', children=[])
])

['States', ['Kansas', ['Lawrence', 'Topeka'], 'Illinois']]
```

Comment: I updated the answer to use `title` following the class you added to the question.